# Better way of sending bulk requests to a remote API with Django Celery?

Tags: django, django-celery, bulk, django-celery-beat

I have users table with 24K users on my Django website and I need to retrieve information for each of my users by sending a request to a remote API endpoint which's rate limited (15 requests/minute).

So my plan is to use the Celery periodic tasks with a new model called "Job". There are two ways  in my perspective:
 1. For each user I will create a new Job instance with the ForeignKey relation to this user.
 2. There will be a single Job instance and this Job instance will have a "users" ManyToManyField field on it.

Then I'll process the Job instance(s) with Celery, for example I can process one Job instance on each run of periodic task for the first way above. But..there will be a huge amount of db objects for each bulk request series...

Both of them seem bad to me since they are operations with big loads. Am I wrong? I guess there should be more convenient way of doing so. Can you please suggest me a better way, or my ways are good enough to implement?

Comment: Do you have to send a request per user? That's almost 27 hours to make all the requests

Comment: @IainShelvington, yes exactly. I can decrease the rate limit by getting an another paid plan, but no need. It's OK to finish it in 27 hours since I'll run this job queue once a week.

Comment: Is this a custom user table? Can you add fields to it?

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes, it is and I can add new fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a field to your user model `last_updated`, you can then set up a task to run every minute that selects the 15 users that were updated last

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, db_index=True)

def task():
    users = User.objects.order_by('last_updated')[:15]
    for user in users:
        # perform API call and update user.last_updated to be now
```

This way you would not have to set up a complicated job queue/table

Comment: Thanks. But, I thought I'd use the same mentality when I need to send a message to these users by using another API endpoint of that remote web service (with another series of Job objects). It'd be awesome if you answer in this way. If you don't have another idea, then I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: Will you be sending a message to all users and is that API rate limited also?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  It's not required to use the ways (Job model instances/manytomanyfields) that I've explained in my question and your approach is good also. But I think it wouldn't be good if I add another field to the user model for each kind of tasks (last_updated, last_message_sent, etc.).